# How do I calm wolves in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I accidentally hit a wolf in Minecraft, how do I calm the wolves that are now standing outside my door?  I can't leave my house because I have 13 angry wolves crowding around my door, and I only have a stone sword.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can choose to kill them if you have the skill and ability to deal with 13 suicidal wolves. Or, you can die to them once and once you leave the game and come back, the wolves will no longer be hostile towards you (Source: my testing in a singleplayer 1.8.8 world). Another way is to simply leave and re-enter the world (thank you, Ben) and the wolves will no longer be hostile towards you. Else, you cannot calm angry wolves directly.

Comment: Thank you.  Lol, I decided to go ahead and attempt to leave my house with nothing but my sword, since my spawn point was just right there, and I managed to defeat them all without taking any damage... IDK how I did that, but I'm not gonna complain lol.

Comment: Good job, I find it hard to deal with 3, let alone 13...

Comment: Edit: you can "calm" them indirectly and painfully if you die to one of them, just tested this in Minecraft 1.8.8 survival world. I'm really sorry about the confusion -- I literally just found that out.

Comment: I would say that reloading the world (quitting and reopening it) would also have the same effect

Comment: Would it be possible for me to add that to the answer? @Ben

Comment: @54D Go for it.

Answer (score 3):

I made a 2 large and 1 long with 4-5 blocks profound. I pushed the angry wolf there, then poured a lava bucket  on  the top of it, waited a sec.. Then felt bad, then it was dead without alarming the others.  (n_n)/

Answer (score -3):

If you're in creative mode, spawn a fox. The wolves will chase the fox instead, leaving you alone.

Comment: If I was in creative mode, I wouldn't need to calm them, as they wouldn't be aggroed to me

Comment: @emilenneleumani the question assumes the person is in survival